# How I can enable google api on server side

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client

I have a android app i am getting serverauthcode and trying to process it here but there is a problem i cant understand. Actually I must access active app user on server side. And i have web application credintals ı added it to playconsole only i have no any url for now

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;



public class run2 {

        private static String REDIRECT_URI ="";

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
             String authCode="4/0AY0e-g64FS0Awt_TdDeDiK6JwyT-gvbg95HrS0ivUBBt12Ke7KzZoqbNqSp7D8zd8R6NPw";
            File secretFile = new File("C:\\Users\\FURKAN\\Downloads\\client_secret.json");

            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(
                        GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), new FileReader(secretFile));
            GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse =
                      new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                          new NetHttpTransport(),
                          GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                          "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
                          clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId(),
                          clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret(),
                          authCode,
                          REDIRECT_URI)
                          .execute();

            String accessToken = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
             
            GoogleIdToken idToken = tokenResponse.parseIdToken();
            GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
            System.out.println(tokenResponse.getIdToken());
    }

}
```

getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:326)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:166)
    at com.bowgame.api.restapi.run2.main(run2.java:44)
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>30.1.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.31.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.30.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.31.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>1.31.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
        <version>1.31.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>1.31.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>1.31.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.31.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>android</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: The Google analytics api sample is the best sample i know of for authorizing with Java you might want to have a look at that you will have to tweek it for what ever api it is you are trying to access https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-java

Comment: TIP: authorization code can only be used once.

Comment: yes you are true authorization code can only be used once. what ı should do after that . It's working now . I think ı must refresh token ? and give me example please with advice :D

Comment: IF your using the library the library should handle all that for you

Comment: // Use access token to call API
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
Drive drive =
    new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
        .setApplicationName("Auth Code Exchange Demo")
        .build();
File file = drive.files().get("appfolder").execute();

Comment: There is no Drive lib ı searced it but ı coudn't find can you look here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access

Comment: Have you tried the drive java quickstart https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java